# Incorrect DateTime interval value php

Tags: php, datetime

When trying to check the difference between two dates I found that when getting the difference between the dates:
31/10/2019 and 01/12/2019.

I was only getting a result of one month. Anyone know how I can fix it?

```
$d1 = new DateTime('2019-10-31');
$d2 = new DateTime('2019-12-01');
$interval= $d1->diff($d2);
var_dump($interval);
```

Returns

```
object(DateInterval)#3 (16) {
  ["y"]=>
  int(0)
  ["m"]=>
  int(1)
  ["d"]=>
  int(0)
  ["h"]=>
  int(0)
  ["i"]=>
  int(0)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Answer (score 1):

Well your difference is 31 days, you can get the days like this.

```
<?php

$d1 = new DateTime('2019-10-31');
$d2 = new DateTime('2019-12-01');

$interval= $d1->diff($d2);

echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Comment: hmm... I use de alias before, but well I hope now is better